# Converting Assembly to Machine Code

Tags: assembly, machine-code, intel-fpga, nios

I'm taking a course now about computer organization and architecture. 
We've been given some exercises to do. One of them is to convert assembly code into machine instructions.

I'm stuck on converting `movia` into a machine instruction.

I know it consists of 2 operations, `orhi` and `addi`.

This is the code in assembly:

```
movia r8, 50000
```

The exercise states that `r0` is `0x0`, and `r8` is `0x8`.

So, the `orhi` would be: `orhi r8, r0, %hiadj(50000)` and the add would be: `addi r8, r8,%lo(50000)`

I've gotten the `orhi` to:

```
    00000 01000 1100001101010000 110100    
___________________r0____r8_______50000________0x34(opcode)
```

But I have to use the `%hiadj` on the 50000! I don't know how to? I've searched around for it a bit but haven't found an answer clear enough.

I'm very new at this but really want to understand! So, how do you use the `%hiadj`? Sorry if the question isn't clear, but if you'd like to help, I'll try and explain more.

Answer (score 1):

`%hiadj` is the 16 most significant bits of its operand, with an adjustment if the 16 least significant bits would be sign-extended by the `movia`.  In the case of `50000`, the 16 most significant bits are `0`, and there is no sign extension.

So `%hiadj(50000)` would simply be `0`.